# numpy - explanation of "np.copy is a shallow copy and will not copy object elements within arrays"

Tags: numpy, copy, shallow-copy

## Background

- [numpy.copy(a, order='K', subok=False)[source]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) says:

> Note that np.copy is ***a shallow copy*** and will not copy object elements within arrays. **This is mainly important for arrays containing Python objects**. The new array will contain the same object which may lead to surprises if that object can be modified (is mutable):

Based on [3.2 Memory layout](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#memory-layout), I suppose array `a` would be pointing to a memory region that contain the 64 bit float numbers.

> Said differently, an array is mostly a contiguous block of memory whose parts can be accessed using an indexing scheme.

[image]

Because the document said `np.copy is a shallow copy and will not copy object elements within arrays`, I supposed the memory region will not be copied but referenced.

However, the copy is not a view to the original array and the memory region/address are different because `x[0] == z[0]` is False after x[0] = 10```.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
z = np.copy(x)
print(f"x.base {x.base} z.base {z.base}")
---
x.base None z.base None

x[0] = 10
print(x[0] == z[0])
---
False

print(f"x.base {x.base} z.base {z.base}")
---
x.base None z.base None
```

### Questions

What is `np.copy(a)` actually copying?

If it is a `shallow copy`, why a different memory area is allocated to `z[0]`? Is it actually copying objects of the array `x` which should be called **deep copy**? Or is it **copy-on-write**?

Or does `shallow copy` mean, "when an element of np array is a mutable container such as list, then np.copy will not deep-copy the content of the container"?

Please help understand what exactly `z = np.copy(x)` does and what happen when assignment operations occur to `z`.

Comment: You don't have an `object` dtype array, so don't worry about `deepcopy`

Comment: If the dtype is object, the array's databuffer contains references to objects elsewhere in memory.  A `copy` will have a new databuffer, but the values will reference the same objects. That's the same problem as with a shallow copy of a nested list.  But with a numeric dtype, having a new databuffer is enough. The new buffer has new values.  That's the regular array copy and doesn't require over thinking.

Answer (score 3):

In python, the `copy.copy()` method performs a `shallow copy`, i.e., only objects of a primitive data types (e.g., `int`, `float` etc.) are coppyied, but constitute objects (e.g., dictionaries) are not, but instead are referenced trhough pointers.

On the other hand, the `copy.deepcopy()` method will copy everything (including composite data structures such as dictionaries), and will result in a new object identical to the first.

In case of the `numpy` module, if you use it for numerical computation as you should (i.e., compute data of one of the numerical [dtypes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)) `copy` will be equivalent to `deepcopy` (as all the **numeric** items of `numpy` are primitive `dtypes`), and will result in a new object identical to the first, which you see as a new data space being allocated for the copied item.

Cheers.